# Different results using google-cloud-vision online and api

Tags: google-vision

I used google vision online in https://cloud.google.com/vision/ to get the detected text for an image file. I received 5 results.

Then I used the api to get the detected text for the same image file. But I only received 3 results and only 1 is exactly the same as one of the online-result.

Can anyone tell how to get the same results?

Comment: Can you share your code, Which mode you are using? Use DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION instead of TEXT_DETECTION

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It happens. Because every time they re-analyze the picture, and Google won't save the last time result for you. I think you could save the result in your database.